# Html table header multi-level layout

Tags: html, css

I need help to achieve a table header layout like the one below

```
X X X X X X     X     X
            Y Y Y Y Y
```

Ideally, the X that doesn't a second header have a  is centered

What I have so far looks like the code below, but it doesn't work

```html
<table>
<thead>
 <tr>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>
   <tr>
    <th>X</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Y</th>
    <th>Y</th>
    <th>Y</th>
    <th>Y</th>
    <th>Y</th>
    <th>Y</th>
   </tr>
  </th>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>X</th>
  <th>X</th>
 </tr>
</thead>
</table>
```

Comment: `tr` should be a child of `tbody` not `th`. You can't just dump rows within cells.

Comment: Ok, but does that help me achieve the layout I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this quite simply by adding two `<tr>` elements to the `<thead>`, and then using `rowspan`:

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th rowspan="2">X</th>
      <th rowspan="2">X</th>
      <th rowspan="2">X</th>
      <th rowspan="2">X</th>
      <th rowspan="2">X</th>
      <th rowspan="2">X</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Y</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Y</th>
      <th>X</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Y</th>
      <th rowspan="2">Y</th>
      <th rowspan="2">X</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Y</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>
```

Comment: Nice solution, but any way to center the headers? and it must be a pain to provide data to this table

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo what do you mean by *center the headers*?

Comment: Have X centered with X - Y, centered vertically?  And as I generate this rows from a template, I needed a more clean solution, not to add a new row to the entire table, is there a way I can just two level one column?

Comment: Didn't mean to say your solution is trash, it works just fine for what I asked, just asking for extra help. If you say you can't help or don't know, I will just mark your answer as right.

Comment: @BrunoMazzardo please see the edit. This centers the headers for you. If you're having trouble generating the markup, you should ask another question.